# Is lazy loading supported in Hibernate Search?

Tags: hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

Is lazy loading supported in Hibernate Search, that is, when I try to find some root indexed entities through Hibernate Search, then does Hibernate Search support lazy-loading annotations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you search for items using Hibernate Search, then it (Hibernate Search) searches the Lucene indexes to find the identifiers of matching documents.  Then, the identifiers are passed off to Hibernate in order to retrieve the actual entities; the entities aren't loaded by Hibernate Search (unless you use projections, in which case you handle the loading of the entities yourself).  Thus, since Hibernate is the one loading the actual entities, it is the only part that needs to be concerned with lazy-loading.